# How do I get upvotes for my answers?

Tags: discussion

There seems to be a lot of implicit and undocumented tips for getting reputation here. Let's start with answers: how do I get upvotes for my answers? Feel free to post more tips here.

Comment: I don't think the way you worded this makes it a good meta question. As it stands now, it isn't even a question...

Comment: I accepted my own answer because it has the highest votes.

Comment: Choose extremely easy languages (such as APL) or extremely hard languages (such as Morning Crescent). Moderately hard languages such as 1+ does not happen to work.

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive Retina is always an exception here - it's a moderately hard language.

Comment: @Third-party'Chef' Oh, alright. Why is it popular and 1+ is not? I'm not good at answering after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Fully explain your answer

If others are able to understand your answers, they have a greater chance of upvoting it, since they can verify it easily. However, if you didn't write an explanation, they might not upvote your answer that frequently.

Answer (score 0):

### If you posted your answer, don't leave yet!

If you leave your answer alone after you posted your answer, others might post solutions with more impressive approaches. If you left you are going to lose all that fun of porting the ideas of other people. The easiest thing to get upvotes is to port others' impressive answers as your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Write an interesting answer

Comment: Interesting answer. I'm very surprised that it's downvoted...

Answer (score -1):

### Answer the newest questions

If you see a new question, immediately try to post an answer to it. Therefore, since the voters can currently only see this answer, they will upvote it anyway.

Comment: This is traditionally called the FGITW (Fastest Gun In The West) effect. While it often does happen (and it's not necessarily a bad thing), I don't think it is a good idea to *promote* it.

Answer (score -6):

### Advertise your answer in the public, e.g. the chat.

If you posted a link to your answer, you might be able to get more upvotes to your answer, since it is made more public. This only works if your answer is creative enough - if your answer is boring, they won't upvote it.

Comment: This seems counterintuitive. If I see an answer being publicised by the author and/or a request for upvotes, I usually downvote.